# What are pros and cons of using uint64_t as an universal address of memory instead of void*?

Tags: c++, c

I'm a rookie of C programming. I found `uint64_t` is used as addresses of buffer rather than `void*` in libibverbs.

```
struct ibv_sge{
    uint64_t addr;
    uint32_t length;
    uint32_t lkey;
}
```

A disadvantage I can think of is its portability. On a 32-bits system, it will causes compilation error or at least memory waste. So why does it do? Are there any benefits?

I also noted there are other alternative approach, such as `uintptr_t`. What's the best approach to describe an universal address of memory?

Comment: Impossible to say without more context

Comment: The `ib` in libibverbs seems to refer to InfiniBand which is a high performance interconnect (I/O) thing. It seems doubtful the `uint64_t addr` is used directly as a pointer, more likely it is used to issue a read or write request to an InfiniBand piece of hardware. That means you are not looking at standard C or C++, but you are looking at a hardware specific protocol. Since InfiBand is not intended for 'small' systems (like your PC or your commodity server), I guess there was never any point bothering with 32bit or smaller address space so the InfiniBand folks went with 64bit at the outset.

Comment: It would be better to use `uintptr_t` — especially if it happens that pointers are not 64-bit.

Comment: This doesn't provide enough context on what you want to know, so it's unclear and/or too broad.

Comment: Your approach will also not represent the addresses correctly on future architectures that have 128-bit or larger pointers.   `uint64_t` is also not supported in C before 1999, or C++ before 2011.   `void *` will work in all these cases.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is always preferable to `uint64_t` here because it is both the correct size for the platform and clearly indicates that the intent is to store a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pros and cons of using uint64_t as an universal address of memory

Con:

1. It may be unnecessarily wide when a narrower *universal address* would do.
2. It may be unnecessarily narrow when a wider *universal address* is needed.

C does not have a *universal address*.  The closest is `void *`, yet that only specified to be sufficient for object pointers.  `void *` may be insufficient for function pointers.  Any function pointer type is the same size as another function pointer type.

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. C11dr §6.3.2.3 1
>
> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. §6.3.2.3 8

---

> What's the best approach to describe an universal address of memory?

With C, instead use a `union`.

```
union u_pointer {
  void *obj;
  int (*fun)();
};
```

Access to read and write these members needs careful handling though, as would be the case with any *universal pointer*.

---

Comment: _" `void *` may be insufficient for function pointers"_ - citation needed

Comment: @Alnitak Citations added to support the conclusion.

Comment: (I duplicated the comment myself, not knowing which answer you'd keep)

Comment: @Alnitak Well that is 1 less mystery.  Stack-overflow did go off-line for a while near the post of this answer and likely contributed to the duplication.

Comment: N.B. that the `union` type-punning hack (A) can produce a trap representation and (B) is only defined behaviour in C, not C++. Also, it is only specified in C as performing a naive reinterpretation of the object representation, so I'm not sure any form of valid/usable result is guaranteed.

Comment: @underscore_d This is not a type punning hack but a simple union. `void *` values are save/read via `obj` and function pointers are saved/read via `fun` - no saving as one and reading as the other is implied or should be inferred - no trap representation following that.  Code should save retrieve the same union member, the selection of which is defined by some OP means.  As this is valid in C, answer amended to indicate that.  In C there is no issue.  Unfortunately I see post is dual language tagged and likely should be tagged only one as the best answers are certainly language dependent.

Comment: @chux Oh right. I did wonder if that was the case, but it didn't seem clear, so thanks for clarifying. With that said, why would this not be OK in C++ too? Anyway, yeah, dual-language questions often get muddied by the ways in which the two Standards have diverged over the years, whether in their intended behaviour or at least the clarity/accuracy of whatever wording ended up trying to describe that behaviour.

Comment: @underscore_d I see no reason this will not work in C++, yet do not have the time now to seek supporting docs.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ one shall never need neither `int`, nor `void*` as pointer types, ever.

The library seems to be about 13 000 lines of C. An example of how the structure is used, copied from [the current master](https://github.com/linux-rdma/rdma-core/tree/master/libibverbs):

```
static int pp_post_recv(struct pingpong_context *ctx, int n)
{
        struct ibv_sge list = {
                .addr   = (uintptr_t) ctx->buf,
                .length = ctx->size,
                .lkey   = ctx->mr->lkey
        };
        struct ibv_recv_wr wr = {
                .wr_id      = PINGPONG_RECV_WRID,
                .sg_list    = &list,
                .num_sge    = 1,
        };
        struct ibv_recv_wr *bad_wr;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                if (ibv_post_srq_recv(ctx->srq, &wr, &bad_wr))
                        break;

        return i;
}
```

To me, `.addr` seems like an offset in a buffer. Thus, pointer type would have been misleeding.

Comment: So what type should an implementation of `operator new` return?

Comment: _"one shall never need"_ `int` as a pointer type? Sure, certainly not. But as for `void*` and the `ptr[diff]_t` types? I suspect the situation is not as rosy as you imagine. Not everyone gets to work on projects as neat/high-level as yours; some need to perform arithmetic, type-erasure, &  whatever other mangling on pointers. Implementers of things like the stdlib or Boost are the easiest example that jumps to my mind, followed by those working on embedded or interop projects, but I bet other categories need it sometimes too. Such code should be avoided _if possible_, but sometimes it can't be